# knockout js bind class to the result of a function

Tags: knockout.js

I am using knockout js to set the class of an element depending on the result of an expression, what I would like to know is if it is possible to set the class to the value returned from a function in the view model.

This is what i have at the moment and works:

```
<div data-bind="css: { highlightup : OneDayChange > 0 &&  SevenDayChange > 0}">
</div
```

I would like to have somthing like:

```
<div data-bind="css: { bothValuesIncreasing(); }">
</div
```

**Edit**
for clarification i would like the class to be set by the value returned from the function, but it may not be a boolean value, it could be any string the function returns

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) properties.

```
var vm = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.OneDayChange = ko.observable();
  self.SevenDayChange = ko.observable();
  self.isBothValue = ko.computed(function(){
    return self.OneDayChange() > 0 && self.SevenDayChange() > 0;
  });
}

<div data-bind="css: { highlightup: isBothValue() }">
</div
```

Don't afraid to use those properties for view specific actions. Thats what viewmodels created are.

**Responding to update:**
Custom binding would be a best choise for solving this problem.

Actually I found an answer on [KnockoutJs google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/knockoutjs/css$20class/knockoutjs/qquMVslvb4Y/Q7bHE1mTpLQJ)

Bindings -  https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/wiki/Bindings---class

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/NBmjh/

Comment: Excellent solution by Maestro!

Answer (score 0):

Usual way of doing this is move this logic to viewModel and use dependendObservables

```
viewModel.isHighlightup = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    return this.OneDayChange > 0 && this.SevenDayChange > 0
}, viewModel);

<div data-bind="css: { highlightup : isHighlightup }"></div>
```

Ryan has explained it brilliantly in his post http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/08/simplifying-and-cleaning-up-views-in.html

Comment: In KnockoutJs 2.0.0 dependentObservable renamed to computed for conveniences, dependentObservable is still available via alias.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/12/21/knockout-2-0-0-released/

Comment: AlfeG found great Steve's way of doing this.